# compute a double series

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I am trying to simplify this one to a single summation form:

$\sum_\limits{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_\limits{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+j-1}}{j!n!}\sigma^n y^{n+j-1}$

I have no idea of how to do that,maybe someone can give me some help or hint?thanks!

Comment: do you know the taylor series for the exponential function?

Comment: yeah,this term are from an exponential function, I try to solve the exponential function by using this.

Comment: if I can simplify this into a one-summation form,it might be possible to solve my origin problem.

Comment: see @Marco's answer...

Comment: I don't mean to separate it, I try to make it one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both series are the Taylor series of $e^{x}$. Then $$\sum_{n\geq0}\sum_{j\geq0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+j-1}}{n!j!}\sigma^{n}y^{n+j-1}=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{\left(-\sigma y\right)^{n}}{n!}\sum_{j\geq0}\frac{\left(-y\right)^{j-1}}{j!}=\frac{e^{-\sigma y}e^{-y}}{y}=\frac{e^{-y\left(\sigma+1\right)}}{y}.$$ You can write it as a single series using again the Taylor series $$\frac{e^{-y\left(\sigma+1\right)}}{y}=\frac{1}{y}\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}y^{k}\left(\sigma+1\right)^{k}}{k!}.$$

Comment: i think u  miss a $-1/y?$

Comment: @tired Yes, thank you.

Comment: Is it possible to simplify this double series into one summation form?

Comment: @KennyYang Done.

Comment: maybe using some tricks like http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erdos-BorweinConstant.html ?

Comment: wow that's awesome! thanks a lot!

Comment: @KennyYang You're welcome :)

Comment: @KennyYang You can also accept the answer, if you think it respond to your question.

Comment: okay,sorry I am new to this.